# Jenkins - mass change method/tool to change builds

Tags: linux, api, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have an API that checks for holiday and runs/not runs a build based on the result. The problem now is that I have to manually change Jenkins jobs to include that logic which is obviously very inefficient. Is there a way/tool to quickly add/remove that check or any other checks in the future to specific jobs quickly without going through them one-by-one? I could see maybe using Jenkins API as one option, is there anything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User JobDSL you can programmatically solve your problems in one place with a Groovy DSL.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin